# Why is XPath last() function not working as I expect?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test. I need to get the last element inside another element, so I used `last()` function, but the problem is that it doesn't always bring me the last one when I apply :

```
//a//b[last()]
```

to

```
 <a> 
   <l>
     <b>asas</b> 
   </l>
   <b>as</b>
 </a>
```

to get `<b>as</b>` ,it brings me:

```
<b>asas</b>

<b>as</b>
```

but when I apply it to:

```
 <a>      
   <b>asas</b> 
   <b>as</b>
 </a>
```

it brings me:

```
<b>as</b>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**This is a common source of XPath confusion.**  First the straightforward parts:

- `//a` selects all `a` elements in the document.
- `//a//b` selects all `b` elements in the document that are
  descendants of `a` elements.

Normal stuff so far.  ***Next is the tricky part:***

1. To select the last `b` elements among ***siblings*** (beneath `a` elements):

   ```
   //a//b[last()]
   ```

   Here, the filtering is a part of the `b` selection criteria because `[]` has a higher precedence than `//`.
2. To select the last `b` element ***in the document*** (beneath `a` elements):

   ```
   (//a//b)[last()]
   ```

   Here, the `last()` is an index on the list of all selected `b` elements because `()` is used to override the default precedence.

Comment: it worked but could you explain a bit more, I'm quite confused :(

Comment: either of `//a//b` and `(//a//b)` have the same result when I check them at [link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath)

Comment: Yes, but `//a//b[last()]` and `(//a//b)[last()]` do not select the same.  Answer updated with an expanded explanation.

Comment: so that is why when I apply `//a//b[last()]` to `<a><l><b>as</b><b>asasas</b></l><b>asas</b></a>` I get `<b>asasas</b>

<b>asas</b>`  makes sense now, thanks

Comment: just one more question, where should i go to learn the exact behavior of these functions? do you know any online source?

Comment: The original [**XPath Recommendation**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is remarkably readable.  Don't miss the [**location path examples**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths)

Comment: I found this explanation: `/bookstore/book[last()] Selects the last book element that is the child of the bookstore element` from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) is it the same as what you said, or are they wrong?

Comment: Yes, that statement is correct, but my and Michael Kay's answers make a more subtle point than that.

Comment: this is really helpful and missed by at least 5 other answers for similar questions.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's easiest to understand the behaviour if you remember that "//" is an abbreviation for "/descendant-or-self::node()/", and that the step "b" is an abbreviation for "child::b". So

```
//b[last()]
```

is an abbreviation for

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::b[position()=last()]
```

Which means "Select every node in the document (except attributes and namespaces). For each of these nodes, form a list of the child elements named "b", and select the last element in this list".

You ask for sources of information. @kjhughes recommends reading the XPath 1.0 recommendation, and indeed, it is a lot more readable than many specs. But it can be a bit terse at times; it occasionally feels like solving a crossword puzzle. My "XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference" (which also includes a lot of material on XPath) was written for people who want a deep understanding of how the language works, but explained in plainer English. This particular topic is on page 627, and it's easy enough to find a pirated copy on the web if you want to see how it's covered. But I'd recommend buying a legal copy, because scrolling through 1300 pages of scanned PDF is not much fun.

Comment: ***XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference*** is available from the [**publisher here**](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0470192747.html) or [**Amazon here**](http://www.amazon.com/XSLT-2-0-XPath-Programmers-Reference/dp/0470192747/)    Buy it.  As developers, the cost is nothing compared with the time understanding it will save you.  Michael Kay is extremely generous with his time here and across the net, btw, so you can see how well he writes on complex topics; his book is even better.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your time and help:)