# Cannot get the XPath function last() to work

Tags: java, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am testing a web app in selenium. I am trying to get the last comment on the most recent post of a feed, the most recent post is always at the top. The last comment is always at the bottom of the thread below the post.

Right now, in my test feed, there are two comments on the most recent post.

The first one has this XPath:

```
/html/body/main/div/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]
```

The second one has this XPath:

```
/html/body/main/div/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]
```

I am trying to use the following XPath to always get the last comment on the most recent post:

```
/html/body/main/div/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[last()]/div[2]/div[2]
```

When I do this, chrome dev tools does not recognize an element with that xpath. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you posted a [mcve] ***that included the HTML***.

Comment: Does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754697/why-is-xpath-last-function-not-working-as-i-expect ?

Answer (score 1):

try this xpath: added () in your xpath for more details kindly read references

```
(/html/body/main/div/section/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div)[last()]/div[2]/div[2]
```

Reference-
https://www.javatpoint.com/webdriver-locating-strategies-by-xpath-using-last

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/01/select-checkbox-using-position-and-last.html

Answer (score 0):

use findElements to return a list. Then you can select the first or last element in that list as needed. without your HTML it's tough to determine exact steps. Something like this should help you:

```
    List<WebElement> posts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//postElements"));
    WebElement firstPost = posts.get(0);
    List<WebElement> comments = firstPost.findElements(By.xpath("//commentsXpath"));
    WebElement lastComment = comments.get(comments.size() - 1);
```