# Find the last div in XPATH / Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am new to the subject and my problem is quite simple but I think I am not doing it right: :'(

I'm trying to get the last element of a div because its number is dynamic.
I am using selenium and it goes something like this :

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/**div[17]**/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a")
```

I would like to recover the value of the "div [17]" which will become "div [18]" or later 19 for example.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/**div[last()]**/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a")
```

I'm blocking a bit, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please [edit your question and post your relevant HTML?

Comment: please try the updated answer  , else share the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div")

lastelement = test[-1].find_element_by_xpath("./div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/a")
```

use find elements , it returns full elements and then use -1 to get the last element from the array

Comment: you should use find_elements not find_element

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this ? [Why is XPath last() function not working as I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754697/why-is-xpath-last-function-not-working-as-i-expect)

Perhaps you need to round your div block with parentheses and use the double slash '//(div)[last()]'

Comment: I tried several variants but I still have errors